# error while creating a composite index

Tags: mongodb

I work on a mongodb database where I have a request that does collscan to optimize the operation to IXSCAN

I tried to create a composite index ,with the following syntax

```
db.person.createIndex({"nom":1}, {"age":1},{background:true})
```

I got this error message `MongoServerError: BSON field 'createIndexes.commitQuorum' is the wrong type 'object', expected types '[long, int, decimal, double, string']`

Does anyone have any ideas on this error please?